# Eclipse E4: How to Drag from an OS window (like file dialog) to an eclipse m-part view?

Tags: eclipse, drag-and-drop, operating-system, eclipse-rcp

I have Drag and drop working fine within a test Eclipse E4 application. But i'm trying to drag from an OS window (the file dialog) to my mpart view. No such luck. And the DropTarget functions are not firing at all, even though the part (viewer) is setup to receive drops (drop target events). And it works fine from within my app, such as dragging from another mpart view.

I noticed that this can be done in the Eclipse (IDE) itself. How is this enabled in any general Eclipse (E4) application?

Thanks.

Comment: What `Transfer` types are you specifying?

Comment: Just the TextTransfer. I thought that was generic enough to work for most cases. I'm using that to actually transfer node items (that aren't actually text) from 1 view to another.\

Comment: You probably need `FileTransfer`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Unfortunately, still does not work. Also tried URLTransfer. Maybe gonna try some of the others (ResourceTransfer) etc., but I doubt it will work. As I said, I'm not getting any events from dragging the file from the OS file dialog, such as dragOver, etc. They aren't firing at all. Not sure if there is some sort of hook to tie in the os. As I said, it works for the Eclipse IDE (I can drag many files from the os dialog right into an Eclipse IDE window), so there must be some way to do it. Any more ideas appreciated. Thx.